# Distribution of aar file along with . class files to allow to debug without modification

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

As part of our project we need to develop different feature set as library module. Other developers should be able to debug code but not able to modify it. Can we provide .class files along with aar file using some mechanism (for example jcenter or Maven)?

How Android provide source files, as we are able to use them as aar file and also debug Activity classes etc but can only extend, not modify?

Answer (score 0):

The `.class` files are just inside the `aar` file.

If you want to provide the source when you update the artifact on Maven, just provide a `jar` with sources and/or javadoc.

If you are using the bintray plugin you can use something like:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

bintray {
    //..
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        //...
      }        
    }
}
```

More [info here.](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/6f62fe1492726d848d6d)